# XSD to describe a web page for parsing into C# objects

Tags: c#, xml, xsd

I'm working on automating interaction with websites using Selenium. In order to avoid defining complex classes for the sites themselves I thought it would be good to have XML documents describing the sites that I can serialize into C# objects and do the necessary interactions.

I have a base class called Element that is the base for all objects - site, page and items on the pages like buttons and text boxes:

```
public class Element
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string XPath { get; set; }
    public Element Parent { get; set; }
    public Collection<Element> Children { get; set; }
}
```

I would like my XML file to looks something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Site>
  <Name>MyTestSite</Name>
  <Url>http://mytesturl</Url>
  <Children>
    <Page>
      <Address>HomePage</Address>
        <Children>
            <Button>
              <Name>SomeButton</Name>
              <Id>SomeID</Id>
              <XPath>SomePath</XPath>
              <Enabled>True</Enabled>
              <Action>OpenLoginDialog</Action>
            </Button>
            <Dialog>
              <Name>LoginPopUpDialog</Name>
              <Children>
                <StaticText>
                  <Name>LoginSuccessMessage</Name>
                  <Id>SomeID</Id>
                  <XPath>SomePath</XPath>
                  <Value>Hello</Value>
                </StaticText>
                <Button>
                  <Name>OkButton</Name>
                  <Value>SomeString</Value>
                  <Id>SomeID</Id>
                  <XPath>SomePath</XPath>
                  <Action>DialogDismiss</Action>
                </Button>
              </Children>
            </Dialog>

            <CheckBox>
              <Name>SomeCheckBox</Name>
              <Id>SomeID</Id>
              <XPath>SomePath</XPath>
              <Enabled>True</Enabled>
              <Checked>True</Checked>
            </CheckBox>
        </Children>
    </Page>
  </Children>
</Site>
```

My understanding was that I have to create complex types for the nodes I want to put in the document such as Page, Dialog, Button and so on. So I declared an Element complex type and used it as a base for the others as such:

```
<xs:complexType name="Element">
<xs:sequence>
    <xs:element type="xs:string" name="Name"/>
    <xs:element type="xs:string" name="Id"/>
    <xs:element type="xs:string" name="XPath"/>
    <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="Children">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence minOccurs="0">
        <xs:element ref="Element" />
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:complexType name="Site">
<xs:complexContent>
    <xs:extension base="Element">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element type="xs:string" name="Url"/>
    </xs:sequence>
    </xs:extension>
</xs:complexContent>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:complexType name="Page">
<xs:complexContent>
    <xs:extension base="Element">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element type="xs:string" name="Address"/>
    </xs:sequence>
    </xs:extension>
</xs:complexContent>
</xs:complexType>
```

But when I try to serialize it the only object that gets initialized is the site. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to Note : the XSD file has no relation at all with the problem you are facing. because the XSD file is just to validate the xml file (if it is adhere some rules you define or not).

The problem is in your C# code. because the XmlSerializer class is responsible for Serialize / de-Serialize the object to/from xml tags.

I think you are missing some attributes for the "Childern" property and the "Parent" property in the "Element" class, try the following

```
public class Element
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string XPath { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName="TextBox", Type = typeof(TextBox))]
    [XmlElement(ElementName="Page", Type = typeof(Page))]
    [XmlElement(ElementName="Button", Type = typeof(Button))]
    [XmlElement(ElementName="Dialog", Type = typeof(Dialog))]
    public Element Parent { get; set; }

    [XmlArray("Children", IsNullable = false)]
    [XmlArrayItem(Type = typeof(TextBox))]
    [XmlArrayItem(Type = typeof(Page))]
    [XmlArrayItem(Type = typeof(Button))]
    [XmlArrayItem(Type = typeof(Dialog))]
    public Collection<Element> Children { get; set; }
}
```

Note : 
1- you must add [XmlArrayItem] attribute on the "Children" property, for each subclass of the "Element" base class to make "XmlSerializer" able to handle with it.

2- you must add [XmlElement] attribute on the "Parent" property, for each subclass of the "Element" base class to make  "XmlSerializer" able to handle with it.

if you have any question, please let me know to.

Cheers

Comment: Awesome, thanks, that sorted me out! One question: you added two Notes about [XmlArrayItem] attribute and [XmlElement] attribute on the subclasses but these attributes are only valid on "Property, Field, Parameter or ReturnValue" declarations. Did you mean adding these attributes to their extra fields they define on top of Element?

Comment: Yes , this is what I meant (adding those attributes to the top of the property which of type of classes that you define like Textbox , Page, Button), I did Not meant to add those attributes on top of the class defintion.
sorry , for being late to answer you, but I was very busy, and very happy that this solved your problem, u r always welcome. @RekaB

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Site site = new Site()
            {
                name = "MyTestSite",
                url = "http://mytesturl",
                children = new Children()
                {
                    page = new Page()
                    {
                        address =  "HomePage",
                        children = new Children()
                        {
                            button = new Button()
                            {
                                name = "SomeButton",
                                id = "SomeID",
                                xPath = "SomePath",
                                enabled = true,
                                action = "OpenLoginDialog"
                            },
                            dialog = new Dialog()
                            {
                                name = "LoginPopUpDialog",
                                children = new Children()
                                {
                                    staticText = new StaticText()
                                    {
                                        name = "LoginSuccessMessage",
                                        id = "SomeID",
                                        xPath = "SomePath",
                                        value = "Hello"
                                    },
                                    button = new Button()
                                    {
                                        name = "OkButton",
                                        value = "SomeString",
                                        id = "SomeID",
                                        xPath = "SomePath",
                                        action = "DialogDismiss"
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                            checkBox = new CheckBox()
                            {
                                name = "SomeCheckBox",
                                id = "SomeID",
                                xPath = "SomePath",
                                enabled = true,
                                m_checked = true
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            };

            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Site));

            StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(FILENAME);
            serializer.Serialize(writer, site);
            writer.Flush();
            writer.Close();
            writer.Dispose();

            XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Site));
            XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(FILENAME);
            Site newSite = (Site)xs.Deserialize(reader);
        }
    }
    [XmlRoot("Site")]
    public class Site
    {
        [XmlElement("Children")]
        public Children children { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("Name")]
        public string name { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("Url")]
        public string url { get; set; }
    }
    [XmlRoot("Children")]
    public class Children
    {
        [XmlElement("Page")]
        public Page page { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("Button")]
        public Button button { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("Dialog")]
        public Dialog dialog { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("CheckBox")]
        public CheckBox checkBox { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("StaticText")]
        public StaticText staticText { get; set; }

    }
    [XmlRoot("Page")]
    public class Page
    {
        [XmlElement("Address")]
        public string address { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("Children")]
        public Children children { get; set; }

    }

    [XmlRoot("Button")]
    public class Button
    {

        [XmlElement("Name")]
        public string name { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("Value")]
        public string value { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("Id")]
        public string id { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("XPath")]
        public string xPath { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("DialogDismiss")]
        public string dialogDismiss { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("Enabled")]
        public Boolean enabled { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("Action")]
        public string action { get; set; }
    }
    [XmlRoot("Dialog")]
    public class Dialog
    {

        [XmlElement("Name")]
        public string name { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("Children")]
        public Children children { get; set; }

    }
    [XmlRoot("CheckBox")]
    public class CheckBox
    {
        [XmlElement("Name")]
        public string name { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("Id")]
        public string id { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("XPath")]
        public string xPath { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("Enabled")]
        public Boolean enabled { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("Checked")]
        public Boolean m_checked { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot("StaticText")]
    public class StaticText
    {
        [XmlElement("Name")]
        public string name { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("Id")]
        public string id { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("XPath")]
        public string xPath { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("Value")]
        public string value { get; set; }

    }

}
```